# How gateway router delivers the packet for host in its local network (with only private IP address like 192.168.2.101)?

Tags: ip, ip-address, local, router, private

When I send a request to web-server from one of my computers connected to home wi-fi router - how the response packet finds its way back to my computer and not to the other?
All computers in my local network have only one public IP and different private Ips (starting with 192.168...) - but source address in outgoing IP packet will be that public IP, so the destination IP for response packet will be also that public IP.
Where is the information about private IP (like 192.168.2.101) stored?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), several private IP addresses can share single public IP.

In both [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure) each packet contains a source IP and a source port (along with a destination IP and port). When a machine in private network sends request to public server, NAT device/router overwrites private source IP+source port in the request packet with the public IP of the router and some unique port, and stores original source IP+port pair and overwritten source port in Translation Table. Remote server responds to public IP of the router+overwritten port number, router does a search in Translation Table by overwritten port number, and put original private ip+port into response packet and sends it to private machine (to original IP+port). Image from Wikipedia:

[image]

([more detailed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation))

So the answer is: Translation Table on router allows to distinguish computers in local network and deliver responses to correct local machines.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So the answer may be reworded as "for TCP-IP networks, NAT encode the private IP into some fake port number remembering this info in its memory, and then add this "port number" into TCP packet header. When response TCP packet comes in, NAT decode incoming port number from the packet to actual private IP-address".